# How can you save an edited page using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, contenteditable

Say I have an html page with several contenteditable attributes set to "true". I like to save the new information, like in WordPress. I prefer to use just PHP for this, but a little help from JavaScript is welcome.

I have searched, but I could not find exactly what I was looking for. How can I transmit the edited information to a PHP script, like submitting a form? Is there a $_GET/$_POST variable, can I use JavaScript to realtime update the information by ID's to inputs, or am I completely searching in the wrong direction?

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a place for us doing all the job for you.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. What did you try? What is the expected result? Can you show us some code? Please [read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it.

Comment: I already searched stackoverflow a while ago, no fitting results. Also other websites didn't tell me much about actually saving the page.

Comment: The question is: how can I save the page, or get the content of specific elements by id, and send it to a PHP script to edit it, somehow? Is there a $_GET/$_POST variable to use, or can I realtime update hidden inputs using javascript, or am I searching in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question this might be the one([click here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Inline-Editor-For-HTML-Tables-jQuery-fullTable.html)) that you are looking for.You have demos and codes available here. Make sure you searched properly before asking such questions.

Comment: I prefer to work without frameworks, is there a way with just pure code? The best would be to just have everything offline, so I'm independent from other sites. Also I like to learn something of it, to have the most options and knowledge of pure code, not frameworks.